# Why the order of pkg-config make difference

Tags: c, compilation, pkg-config

Today I try to compile the hello world example from [gstreamer tutorial](http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735)

When I was compiling the code with command

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10` basic-tutorial-1.c
```

I got the  undefined reference error.

However, if I tried

```
gcc basic-tutorial-1.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10`
```

It worked...
Can anyone give me some tips about the order of the pkg-config? 
Thanks !

Comment: libs have to appear after the object files, or other libraries, in which they are used.  Tad counter intuitive, but the linker doesn't pull in all the functions in a library, only the ones previously called by those listed in front of it.

Comment: Get it. Thanks for your explanation, now I can summary this idea in my mind more logically.